# iPhone version of app shows only upper corner of screen

Tags: ios, screen, uistoryboard

I have made a universal app that has been showing up perfectly on iPad (both mini and full size), but now when I test on iPhone (both 3.5 and 4 inches) only some  of the screen shows up on initialization.

Storyboard for iPhone:

[image]

In the simulator (it looks the same on a physical device):

[image]

For some reason only the upper left corner shows up, and I can't figure out what's causing this.

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Are you loading the iPhone storyboard when running on iPhone. You can set this in the project settings in the general tab.

Comment: Thanks @dasdom !!! so very simple, but so usefull to me

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: absolutely. Quick and efficient.